# ipad/iphone css transition with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, ios, css, mobile, transition

I have a hidden panel that when you click on a link the panel slides in. The panel is fine on all desktop web browsers. However on ipad and iphone when you click the, link to trigger the css animation, the panel just appears with no slide in animation. But then when you close it the transition works from this point, allowing you to open and close the panel seeing the transition. It seems to just be broken on the first trigger of the panel.

Here is a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vr7DL/) of my code.

And here is my code:

```
.workIndvWrapper {
display: none;
z-index:9999;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 75%;
background-color: #ff0000;
overflow-y: auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-moz-box-shadow: -3px 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: -3px 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-webkit-transition: .4s -webkit-transform ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .4s -moz-transform ease-in-out;
transition: .4s transform ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
-moz-transform: translateX(100%);
transform: translateX(100%);
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;  }
.showPanel {
-webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
-moz-transform: translateX(0px);
transform: translateX(0px);
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}



$('#sauceThumb').click(function () {
    if($('#sauceDet').show() )  // don't do anything if panel is already being shown
    {    
        $('#cover').fadeIn(200);
        $('#mainContent').addClass('blur');
        $('#sauceDet').addClass('showPanel').show();
        $('.blankOut').addClass('show');

    }    
});


$('.close, #cover').click(function () 
{

    $('#sauceDet, #rodDet, #portDet ').removeClass('showPanel');
    $('#mainContent').removeClass('blur');
    $('#cover').fadeOut(200);
    $('.blankOut').removeClass('show');
});
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with transitions not working on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to remove the `display: none;` on the `.workIndvWrapper` CSS element ! (Works for me on JS fiddle)